# Access ODBC linked table to SQL Server allows inserts but not updates

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Based on Web readings, I built a new ODBC connection, carefully looking for subtle configuration parameters that might suggest fostering updates, but none were found. Then I tested the new link.

To Re-Test my issue:

1) I created the following table on SQL Server 2005:

```
[TestTbl]

column1: Key      Type:Integer
Column2: Name     Type:varchar(5)
```

Populated as follows

```
   Key     Name
   ===     ====
    1      Apple
    2      Bear
    3      Cat
```

2) Then in Access 2007, created a link to the SQL Server table TestTbl using my latest ODBC connection.

3) Next successfully inserted the following new records into the SQL Server table using the link and executing my inserts from Access 2007:

```
   Key     Name
   ===     ====
    4      Dog
    5      Elephant
```

4) Finally I tried to execute the following simple update query:

```
   UPDATE dbo_TestTable SET dbo_TestTable.TestName = "CatNip"
   WHERE (((dbo_TestTable.TestKey)=3));
```

I got the error message "Operation must be an updateable query"

5) Out of frustration, I inserted another record

```
   Key     Name
   ===     ====
    6      Nonsense
```

Then I posted this question asking for help.

Can anyone please explain why I can insert new records to the linked table but I cannot update existing records?

Comment: varchar(50) was data type of Column2

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo, but your columns are called Key and Name but your INSERT statement refers to TestKey and TestName.

Comment: This is a linked table, yes? Are you sure you have a primary key?

Comment: Resolved using Pass Thru Query

Comment: check if access database is not in readonly mode.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is because there is either no primary key defined or when you linked the table in Access the Primary key was not defined. Re-add the linked table (delete and add) and select a primary key field, in this case column1

Comment: This is most likely the correct answer. Consider using an ADP file instead in future.